# How do clear the search value after deleting the associated filter and to avoid the clearing of all filters after clearing the search value?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

#### How do clear the search value after deleting the associated filter?

For example. I added filter: `{gender: 'female'}`. After this type in the search `Mar`.
After this clear filter in column `name`.
I want to clear the search value. For this, I listen to the event of the `filter`. And if the value of the filter is equal to the search value then clear this.
Maybe exists a more better approach.

#### How to avoid clear all filters after the clearing search value?

```js
const dataSource = kendo.data.DataSource.create({
  data: [{
      name: 'Harry',
      gender: 'male'
    },
    {
      name: 'Marry',
      gender: 'female'
    },
    {
      name: 'Lora',
      gender: 'female'
    }
  ]
});

const gridConfig = {
  toolbar: [
    'search'
  ],
  search: {
    fields: ['name']
  },
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: dataSource,
  columns: [{
    field: 'name'
  }, {
    field: 'gender'
  }]
};

$('#grid').kendoGrid(gridConfig);

$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').bind('filter', onFilter);
const searchElement = $('#grid input.k-input');

function onFilter(e) {
  const searchValue = searchElement.val();
  if (e.filter) {
    const isExistsFilter = e.filter.filters.some(filter => {
      return gridConfig.search.fields.some(field => {
        return filter.field === field && filter.value === searchValue;
      });
    });
    if (!isExistsFilter && searchValue) {
      searchElement.val('');
    }
  } else {
    searchElement.val('');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1021/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: I have found it is better to either use the search bar, or column filtering, but not both together. Do you need both?

Comment: @ezanker, yes, I need both